# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding a Collection With a Prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to bind a collection using a prefix, like so

```
public ActionResult Whatever([Bind(Prefix = "Prefix")] CustomModel[] models)
```

I created form elements using

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Prefix.models[" + i + "].Property") %>
```

which generated html inputs like this

```
<input id="Prefix_models[0]_Property" name="Prefix.models[0].Property" />
```

My problem is that the default model binder will not bind with a prefix. I get null for the models arg in the action method.

If I strip the prefixes from the html and remove the Bind attribute, everything works fine. I cannot imagine that the default model binder won't handle a prefix on a collection, so I must be doing something wrong.

Please help. Cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Prefix* inside of [Bind] isn't prepended to the parameter name, it replaces the parameter name entirely.  So if your action method has this signature:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Prefix = "foo")] string[] bar) { ... }
```

The the binder expects `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, etc.

Comment: DOH! Rough day. Thanks for setting my head straight!

Answer (score 1):

UpdateModel() and TryUpdateModel() take a parameter for prefix.  Have you tried that?