# Why doesn't data persist when changing ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razor/mvc3 application.  I am attempting to put 2 forms on one view and was having trouble with data persisting over both forms. I added an extension method that changes the templateinfo by adding a prefix to the fields' ids.  Unfortunately, the data from the inputs isn't persisting across posts at all now, and I'm not sure what else I need to add to it to make data persist. Here it is:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
    {
        return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
    }
    //this is an extension helper class for input id prefixes for the BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope extension method
    private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
    {
        private TemplateInfo TemplateInfo;
        private string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

        public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            TemplateInfo = templateInfo;

            previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
        }
    }
```

I am using this method like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn","Account"))
{
    using (Html.BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope("LoginForm"))
    { 
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
}
```

to change the prefixes on the input field ids. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

ViewData does not persist across posts. You need either TempDate (valid for the next request) or Session here (or the Cache)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be confusion, the purpose of this extension method is to change the prefixes on the input fields. which it does both before and after postback.  The problem is that now that the ids are changed, data is no longer persisting in those input fields. I have updated my question to reflect my usage of this extension method.

Comment: Why do you need a special prefix here going outside the default mvc helper realm? How are they not persisting? Your data gets posted to the server - which now can't map that field to something in the model since the names are different. You can try the Bind attribute and specify the prefix as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319102/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-a-collection-with-a-prefix